# How to extend pg-promise interface with function

Tags: javascript, node.js, pg-promise

I have a node.js module `pg-promise` instantiated as follows.

```js
const pgp = require('pg-promise')();

// Database connection details;
const cn = {
    host: 'localhost', // 'localhost' is the default;
    ...
}


// Create db connection and verify it
var db = pgp(process.env.DATABASE_URL || cn);
db.one('Select version()')
    .then(data => {
        log.info('Connected: ', data);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        log.error("Error connecting to db", error);
    })

// extension methods
db.findById = function (table, id) {
    log.debug('read ', table, id);
    return db.one('Select * from ' + table + ' where id = $1', id);
}

module.exports = db;
```

The db object is an instance of interface type `pgPromise.IDatabase<{}, pg.Iclient>`

I would like to be able to call the functions provided by this lib along with my own functions.:

```js
const db = require('../db');

db.any('Select query..')
  .then(data => { res.send(data); })
  .catch(err => { log.error(err); });

db.findById('users',1)
  .then(data => { res.send(data); })
  .catch(err => { log.error(err); });
```

But when I run it I get the error

```
TypeError: db.findById is not a function
```

I tried this too but with the same effect.

```js
module.exports = db;
module.exports.findById = function()...;
```

Only one sollution I could come up with was this:

```js
module.exports = {
  db: db,
  findById: function(){
    ...
  }
}
```

But it is now ugly to use it other modules, as I need always to ask specificaly for the `db` property.

Comment: You should check out [pg-promise-demo](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise-demo), which shows how to do it right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the author of [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise).

---

Database protocol in [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise) is extendable, supporting event [extend](https://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/global.html#event:extend) that lets you extend the protocol on all levels. You need this level of automation, because when it comes to the essential [Tasks](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise#tasks) and [Transactions](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise#transactions), which encapsulate the allocated connection, the protocol becomes dynamic, and so you need a special provision to make the protocol extension work automatically, which is exactly what event [extend](https://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/global.html#event:extend) does.

In order to understand it better, I wrote [pg-promise-demo](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise-demo) to show how to do it correctly, plus some other high-level stuff that comes useful most of the time.

Comment: I don't see what the question has to do with the [database protocol](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/protocol.html)?

Comment: @Bergi And what that link got to do with my answer?  - nothing either. It is about the library's protocol extension.

Comment: You might want to clarify then what the term "database protocol" means in the context of the pg-promise library.

Answer (score 0):

`pg-promise` seems to use an annoying pattern where they freeze every object and make every property read-only, so you'll be unable to simply add properties to it manually like you're attempting. The library supports extensions in the [`extend`](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/global.html#event:extend) property of `initOptions` like this:

```
const initOptions = {
  extend(obj, dc) {
    obj.findById = function() {
      ...
    }
    //add other extension methods or properties here
  }
};
const pgp = require('pg-promise')(initOptions);

//now any databases created with pgp will contain those extension methods
```

Alternatively, you can define a Proxy over your export object that defers either to the db or to your own custom function:

```
const extension = {
  findById: function() {
    ...
  },
  //other functions
};

module.exports = new Proxy(extension, { get(target, name) {
  if(db[name] !== undefined) return db[name];
  return target[name];
});
```

But you should prefer the natively supported way to do this using `initOptions`.

Comment: There is nothing annoying in preventing something that you are not supposed to do in the first place. [pg-promise-demo](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise-demo) shows how to do it the right way. And the hack you are doing here is wrong, and it won't work, neither for tasks no for transactions.

Comment: @vitaly-t Sorry, I just find it a little counterintuitive to lock the exported object, especially if you provide a way to modify it before locking anyway. Have never seen another module do that before. I've added the recommended extension method to the answer.

Comment: It was locked for a very good reason, to prevent it being hacked, the way you tried to hack it, because it won't work, and it cannot work, because the protocol is dynamic, just as you get inside tasks and transactions. So if it annoyed you, and thus discouraged from doing that hack, that's for the better, to let you know that perhaps you are doing something wrong :)

Comment: @vitaly-t I am not sure what you mean, so perhaps you could help me understand. I typically view a module's export as a simple javascript object exposing a set of functions to interact with the library. As long as you don't replace one of those functions, you can extend the object freely and totally safely. What do you mean by "the protocol is dynamic"? Do you mean the interface exposed by a `db` instance changes over the usage of the module?

Comment: The protocol is generated once on the root-level `db` object, and every time you call methods `task` or `tx`, which is what makes it dynamic.